# Need merge modules from VS2005

Tags: visual-studio, merge-module

I'm trying to use a merge module in my setup-project. But it seems like there are dependencies in it that require earlier versions of a couple of merge modules than I have (I've got VS2008).

I need these files from VS2005:

```
Microsoft_VC80_ATL_x86.msm 
Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86.msm 
Microsoft_VC80_MFC_x86.msm

policy_8_0_Microsoft_VC80_ATL_x86.msm
policy_8_0_Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86.msm
policy_8_0_Microsoft_VC80_MFC_x86.msm
```

Could anyone please point me to a place where I can download them or make a zip and upload to http://www.zshare.net/ and provide me with the link?

I'm sure they are shipped with Visual Studio 2005 Express as well, but I can't find where to download it either.

/P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe the merge modules are distributed outside of Visual Studio, so you'll need to install that to have access to them. If Microsoft does not distribute these outside of VS, I would be wary of asking someone else to do so, as it may be violating their license agreement.

Once Visual Studio 2005 SP1 Express is installed, you'll be able to find the modules at:

```
%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Merge Modules\Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86.msm
```

Comment: Ok, if that is the case, where can I find VS2005 express? I only seem to find VS2008 express.

Comment: VC++ 2005: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vstudio/aa700736.aspx
SP1: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=7B0B0339-613A-46E6-AB4D-080D4D4A8C4E&displaylang=en

Comment: Thanks! =) You've been a great help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that these are added automatically when you add the 2005 Merge Module into your setup project. That's what it did for me.

The merge modules are located in a file called cr_net_2005_mergemodules_mlb_x86.zip

Answer (score 0):

When you install Visual Studio 2005 in features to install you must make sure to check:

- Tools for Redistributing Applications

  - Redistributable Merge Modules