# Microsoft_VC80_ATL_x86.msm vs Microsoft_VC90_ATL_x86.msm

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project

We have a release after years. I am starting with the an old setup project  and modifying it for the updated code. 
One of the source used by the old project is Microsoft_VC80_ATL_x86.msm  (I am only creating a 32bit install. ). I don’t find it on my current machine.  After googling it seems to come from vs 2005 and I can find it if needed. 
This is a desktop UI application.  I am currently in VS2010 world ( for install project as well as application development). 
The question is: 
Shall I replace Microsoft_VC80_ATL_x86.msm  by Microsoft_VC90_ATL_x86.msm? 
Is it preferred to include both Microsoft_VC80_ATL_x86.msm and Microsoft_VC90_ATL_x86.msm?  Does it affect the range of operating systems the application can be installed on? It is clear from my questions that I do not know the exact reason of including these modules. Answer to that is welcome.
I have already read  [Need merge modules from VS2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773926/need-merge-modules-from-vs2005).

Comment: You should remove it entirely.  You ought to only have a dependency on the VS2010 runtime DLLs, like msvcr100.dll and atl100.dll.  Microsoft gave up on the side-by-side install for the DLLs, best thing to do is to use local copies, same directory as the EXE.

Comment: I interpret your answer as:  Don't include Microsoft_VC80_ATL_x86.msm or  Microsoft_VC90_ATL_x86.msm. Don't include any Microsoft msm. Include relevant microsft dlls. That seems logical to me. I am going for it. Please cite any reference if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using only VS 2010 and you need the VC++ runtimes, and you have a setup project then use the merge modules:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235290(v=vs.100).aspx

DO include the merge modules to install to system32. If you don't use the merge modules you may break the sharing rules.

Comment: Dragging this up again, @Hans above mentions "You should remove it entirely. You ought to only have a dependency on the VS2010 runtime DLLs, like msvcr100.dll and atl100.dll", you're saying to include. I'm trying to upgrade from VS2010 to VS2017. I can't obviously find the old MSM files. So should I just remove the references to merge modules from the setup project file? It seems to build okay, any issues with deployment?